Error in Rollup project Vue 3, Typescript
I'm receiving an error related to the rollup.config.js configuration of my Vue3 project.
Erro
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/components/RktIcon/RktIcon.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts (11:7)
 9:   import { useAllTokens } from '../../composables/useAllTokens'
10: 
11:   type Size = 'small' | 'medium'
           ^
    at error (/home/paulo-pr/moskit/moskit-rock-it/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:353:30)
    at Module.error (/home/paulo-pr/moskit/moskit-rock-it/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15237:16)
    at Module.tryParse (/home/paulo-pr/moskit/moskit-rock-it/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15968:25)
    at Module.setSource (/home/paulo-pr/moskit/moskit-rock-it/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:15569:39)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/home/paulo-pr/moskit/moskit-rock-it/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:25804:20)


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

You've already added the plugins rollup-plugin-vue', @rollup/plugin-typescript, @rollup/plugin-node-resolve which were theoretically supposed to solve the problem, but I still keep getting the same error.
Below is the content of my rollup.config.js file
rollup.config.js
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/components/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        format: 'esm',
        file: 'dist/library.mjs'
      },
      {
        format: 'cjs',
        file: 'dist/library.js'
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      vue({
        include: /\.vue$/,
        preprocessStyles: true, 
        css: true,
        compileTemplate: true 
      }),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.rollup.json', 
        declaration: true,
        declarationDir: 'dist/types',  
        rootDir: 'src',
        exclude: ['**/__tests__', '**/*.test.ts']
      }),
      nodeResolve({
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue']
      }),
      commonjs(),
      alias({
        entries: [{ find: '@', replacement: 'src' }]
      }),
      json(),
      postcss(),
      terser()
    ],
    external: ['vue']
  }
]


